# Java effective implementation of Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

I have a `file upload` functionality, in which user can upload mutiple file at a same time, for good result I used `Thread processing` like this

```
Thread.start{
  // do file processing 'cause it is a long running process
}
```

Now the problem is, for each file upload `system` will create a `new Thread` so that will lead to system thrashing and someother issues, so now I am looking for a solution where I can create a `Queue` to store all the received files and create minimum number`(say 5 nos)` of `Thread` at a time and process it and again create a set of `Thread` and process.

So for I am looking into [GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/), [Java Thread and Queue](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/) and soon but no idea which is efficient way and what is the existing good solution

Comment: You have started reimplementing the `ExecutorService`. Maybe switch to a pruduction-ready implementation right now?

Comment: Just create one object of type BlockingQueue and 5 threads which have access to that queue and, in a loop, call queue.take(). No problems. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a thread pool or - in Java terms - for an [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html):

```
Executor executor = anExecutor();
executor.execute(aRunnable());
```

The method `anExecutor` should return a new `Executor` instance:

```
Executor anExecutor() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(42); // just an example ...
}
```

Comment: as per `executor` documentation "An Executor is normally used instead of explicitly creating threads". But my problem is to create a queue that stores all request files, and give it to `thread` process.

Comment: @Suganthan Why not simply add all tasks to the executor? It internall handles all those tasks, like a queue. If you need more control over the executor, use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead. The factory methods in `Executors` return such `ExecutorService`s.

Comment: may be my knowledge in `Java Thread` not enough, but I didn't got the clear idea, I am working out some java examples to get clear idea, let me try

Comment: @Suganthan You simply create an executor (or an executor service). Then you simply create your tasks (i.e. the runnables) and pass them to the execute or submit method of the exexcutor (service). That's it. The executor itself internally manages the worker threads that are actually running your tasks.

Comment: but I want to limit the number of threads running. To be clear, if there are 100 request, process the first 10 request first and then 10 and 10 next

Comment: now I got the idea this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html is very clearly explaining your answer